# React - How to track useRef children change

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component (`Comp`) that I've added a `useRef` (`compRef`) to its parameters.
As part of the main useEffect - I'm setting the data of this component.
That data contains an array of strings, and the `Comp` displaying all of them as `input`s -

```
<Comp ref={compRef}>
     <input type="text"/>
</Comp>
```

and

```
data = ["HIDDEN", "data1", "data2", "data3", "data4"]

useEffect(() => { 
     compRef.current.refElement.value = data;
}, []);
```

so now the `Comp` will look like this -

```
<Comp>
<generatedWrap> // should be hidden
    <input value="HIDDEN" />
</generatedWrap>

<generatedWrap>
    <input value="data1" />
</generatedWrap>

<generatedWrap>
    <input value="data2" />
</generatedWrap>

<generatedWrap>
    <input value="data3" />
</generatedWrap>

<generatedWrap>
    <input value="data4" />
</generatedWrap>
</Comp>
```

I want to hide the first input with this `hide` command -

```
compRef.current.refElement.children[0].style.display = "none";
```

The problem is, that with every method (useEffect) I'm using during the mount of the screen, the children are empty. Only after the screen is ready It's working (i.e. triggered by a `<button>`)

I need a way to track the number of children of the ref before the view is mounted, and once it's greater than 1 to fire the `hide` command.

How can I do that?

Comment: Could you please post the full code for `Comp` and the main component (where you use `Comp`).

Comment: I don't have access to ```Comp```, and the main component is quite big - what exactly do you need there?

Comment: Does `Comp` do anything special apart of generating a list of inputs based on `data` and the passed children?

Comment: And with what logic do you want an input to be visible/hidden?

Comment: @ErnestoStifano thanks for the comment - the Comp is generating a pretty frame for the input and adding + and trash buttons near each input. the logic behind the hidden thing is that ```Comp``` doesn't support deleting the last input, so I made a dummy input in the beginning and my plan is to hide it so I could delete the last (/second) one.

Comment: And the dummy input would be `<input type="text"/>`? So, `Comp` renders its children as siblings of the generated inputs?

Comment: yes it will. and it wraps them with another component like <Comp> <SomeWrap> <input type="text"/> <SomeWrap> </Comp> - but I think the idea is the same. - and thanks again about the comment :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok

So after a lot of testing - the only option I found is to add `setTimeout(() => compRef.current.refElement.children[0].style.display = "none")` after the render of the `Comp`.

(After the render there is still only 1 child but the fact that the setTimeout is a-synchronic make it work)

Thank you all for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I've correctly understood the situation, but it seems odd to me.

Keep in mind that in React's paradigm, `refs` are more like an escape hatch, and should be avoided when possible.

Also, beware that for non native components, a `ref` can be forwarded to any element, or be handled in any way, so it is not safe to assume it will be the root element.

In any case, you may proceed as follows:

```
<Comp>
     <input type="text" ref={(ref) => ref && (ref.parentElement.style.display = 'none')} />
</Comp>
```

It is the cleanest way I can think of right now with the information I have.

Please let me know if it works for you.

***Update:***

The function in `ref` is called a [Callback Ref](https://www.reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs). It will receive the corresponding `ref` value as the first argument (the HTML `input` element in this case).

The advantage is that you don't have to detect when `Comp` decides to populate the DOM. The callback ref will be called as soon as the real node is ready.

Comment: you said some really important stuff. about the solution - there will be several inputs (like my new edit) and I want only the first one to be hidden. what exactly passing a function as an argument for the ```ref``` means...?

Comment: I've just updated my answer. For the several inputs doubt, I still don't understand. Is `<generatedWrap>` added by you or by `Comp`? Are the other inputs added by you or by `Comp`? I would suggest you to add `ref={(ref) => ref.parentElement.style.display = 'none'}` to the first input only.

Comment: I'm only writing 1 ```Comp``` and 1 ```input```. the Comp adding the ```generatedWrap``` and all the other ```input```s

Comment: and btw I've added ref={(ref) => ref.parentElement.style.display = 'none'} to the input and it throw me an error of ref = null... I dubugged it and in the first time it calls the function but second time getting the null exception

Comment: @DviN sorry, this is because `ref` is passed as `null` when the component un-mounts. Try the following and let me know: `ref={(ref) => ref && ref.parentElement.style.display = 'none'}`. I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: still not working...:( I've added ```document.getElementsByTagName("generatedWrap").length``` and it prints ```1``` 3 times instead of 5

Comment: @DviN where did you add that? What are you trying to do?

Comment: FYI, accessing the DOM at all indicates something has gone completely off the rails and you need to take a step back. You're going in the wrong direction.

Comment: @ErnestoStifano - I've added it where you told me to - ```<input ref = {(ref) => ref&&.....>```

Comment: @Adam I fully understand you and I hate to change the DOM manually but sometimes when the component is not accessible - the only option is via DOM.... :(

Comment: @DviN - instead of asking how to change the DOM with react, provide enough context to make sure you need to. What is `Comp`? Is it from a open-source library?

Comment: @Adam no...it's our company's library that I need to use, and the guys in the team that developed this said that this request is too rare so they won't add this option and that I need to find a workaround...

Comment: @DviN ok, as you and your company wishes, I'll provide you the workaround. Just tell me what you was trying to do with `document.getElementsByTagName("generatedWrap").length`. Do I have to tell your company that `generatedWrap` is not a valid HTML Tag Name or JSX Component Name?

Comment: @DviN and before I update my answer, how does your team want to pass `data` to `Comp`? What properties does it accept?

Comment: @ErnestoStifano thanks again for the comment :) the ```getElementsByTagName``` is just for testing - I just wanted to check the number of children. all the names here are made up to simplified the question. about the parameters - currently, the only option to pass data is via ```compRef.current.refElement.value = data``` and there are few more parameters but they are irrelevant for this case...

Answer (score 0):

**tldr - don't use refs to manipulate the DOM ever** (unless you're an advanced react developer and know exactly what you're doing, which you aren't because these devs wouldn't be asking these questions on SO).

Don't use refs at all, you're doing React drastically wrong by manually manipulating the DOM.

Just pass the strings as props and let the component worry about displaying them:

```js
const MyParentComponent = () => {

   return <Comp data={["HIDDEN", "data1", "data2", "data3", "data4"]}/>
}
```

If you want to hide a certain input in that child component, then pass another prop, for example:

```js
const MyParentComponent = () => {

   const [indexToHide,setIndexToHide] = useState(0);

   return <Comp data={["HIDDEN", "data1", "data2", "data3", "data4"]} indexOfInputToHide={indexToHide}/>
}
```

and then just let `Comp` worry about it's props and that's it.

It's unclear what you're trying to do so the liklihood that this is the exact code you need is not great. But by continuing to try and use refs and manipulate the DOM, you are fighting against the framework and will end up having a much more difficult time in the future as you're doing react wrong, even if you do manage to come up with a working solution in this case.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer and the tips! :) - Unfortunately, I can't pass any other arguments to ```Comp```. The ```Comp``` is an external component and can't be changed. The only option is to change the DOM manually after its render...